# OpenLayers distance formula

Tags: c++, openlayers, geospatial, openlayers-3

We have two applications: a web application (that uses OpenLayers3) and a C++ application. Currently, there is a mismatch in the formula to compute the distance between two points.

For OpenLayers: we are using the default projection (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html#how-do-i-change-the-projection-of-my-map-).

For the C++ application: We are using the formula given in the subsection 'Ellipsoidal Earth projected to a plane': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance. This is the code:

```
double distanceKMs(Node* a, Node* b)
{
    double latMean = (a->lat + b->lat) / 2.0;
    double lonDiff = b->longi - a->longi;
    double latDiff = b->lat - a->lat;
    double k1 = 111.13209 - 0.56605 * cos(2 * latMean) + 0.00120 * cos(4 * latMean);
    double k2 = 111.41513 * cos(latMean) - 
                0.09455 * cos(3 * latMean) + 
                0.00012 * cos(5 * latMean);

    return sqrt( pow((k1 * latDiff), 2) + pow((k2 * lonDiff), 2));
}
```

We are not primarily concerned about *accuracy* (w.r.t. the actual as-the-crow-flies distance). Our goal is to remove the mismatch between the two systems. Which projection can we use in OpenLayers such that its distance formula can easily (i.e., without the use of any external library) be implemented in C++?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to convert the OpenLayers JavaScript formula to C++.

In order to do this, you should convert `ol.sphere.getDistance` ( OpenLayers v5), previously known as `ol.Sphere.haversineDistance` (OpenLayers v4) function https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v5.1.2/src/ol/sphere.js#L44

On client side, to get point coordinates using longitude, latitude simply use `ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat]`.